# Unable to copy files from directory in shell script

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm writing a shell script on MacOSX for the first time, and I'm a little stuck. I'm creating a website, and wanted a simple way to manage updating my files from my git repo to the localhost server. It's also just an excuse to learn shell scripting. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Removing old Files..."
rm -r  /Library/WebServer/Documents/ServerObserver/*
echo "Copying new Files to WebServer"
cp -r /Users/ajay/Documents/ServerObserverRepo/* /WebServer/Documents/ServerObserver/
echo "Done!"
```

The removing part works fine, but copying does not work. I get this message in my Terminal:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Of course, it didn't copy either. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: It gives you a hint, doesn't it?  Use `-R` instead of `-r`.

Comment: Thanks, but changing to `-R` yielded the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider rsync, as in

```
rsync --delete -a /Users/ajay/Documents/ServerObserverRepo/ /WebServer/Documents/ServerObserver/
```

that removes the need for the rm command and the cp command, and only copies the changed files / removes the deleted ones. :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
cp -r /Users/ajay/Documents/ServerObserverRepo/* /WebServer/Documents/ServerObserver/
```

to

```
cp -r /Users/ajay/Documents/ServerObserverRepo/* /WebServer/Documents/ServerObserver/.
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain what difference the `.` at the end makes?

Comment: . just specified the end of target path , meaning exact location , as you are copying a bunch of files , had you written cp -r /Users/ajay/Documents/ServerObserverRepo/ then /WebServer/Documents/ServerObserver/ would have worked sufficely